# Is it possible to use a serial port-like session in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, serial-port

I am using serial port communications in my [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) webform application:

```
private bool sendSMS(int portNo, string mobNo, string details)
{
    try
    {
        SerialPort SerialPort1 = new SerialPort();
        SerialPort1.PortName = "COM" + portNo.ToString();
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        SerialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
        SerialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
        SerialPort1.Encoding.GetEncoder();
        SerialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
        SerialPort1.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
        SerialPort1.Open();
        SerialPort1.Write("AT" + SerialPort1.NewLine);
        Sleep(500);
        SerialPort1.Write("AT+CMGF=1" + SerialPort1.NewLine);
        Sleep(500);
        SerialPort1.Write("AT+CMGS=" + (char)34 + mobNo + (char)34 +
                                    SerialPort1.NewLine);
        Sleep(1000);
        SerialPort1.Write(details + (char)26);
        Sleep(2000);
        SerialPort1.Close();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    return true;
}
```

This method works when I send in a single message... But when I want to send [SMSes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) in bulk opening and closing port everytime is not a good idea... Is it possible to use a serial port like session in [c#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)?

When I open a port I want it to be open for one hour and then if my time expires I want to close the port and open it the next time... Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an object and in its constructor/initialization call `SerialPort.Open()` and implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) to call `SerialPort.Close()`. For the lifetime of the object, it'll be open.

Something a little more detailed is below (though definitely not a complete solution). The general idea is to encapsulate the port connection lifetime into the object lifetime so that when the object goes out of scope/use and gets cleaned by the [GC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) then so does the port connection.

@jrista makes a good point about needing to handle any error conditions. ErrorReceived will help with that, as well as ol' fashioned error handling throughout this code where necessary.

```
public class SerialPortConnection : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed;
    public SerialPort Port { get; protected set; }

    public SerialPortConnection(int portNo)
    {
        this.Initialize(portNo);
        this.Port.ErrorReceived += this.portError;
        this.Port.Open();
    }

    public void Initialize(int portNo)
    {
        this.Port = new SerialPort();
        this.Port.PortName = "COM" + portNo.ToString();
        /* snip */
        this.Port.Encoding.GetEncoder();
        this.Port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
        this.Port.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
    }

    protected void portError(
        object sender,
        SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler args)
    {
        // Do whatever with the error, maybe need to reopen the socket.
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this.Port.Close();
                this.Port.Dispose(disposing);
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `For the lifetime of the object, it'll be open.` That's barring any complications with the underlying socket. Assuming a socket will live untainted and uninterrupted for any duration of time is asking for trouble. At the very least, Open/Close should be more dynamic, happening in response to activity on the session object, rather than only at its initialization or disposal. +1, but I would probably offer a more thorough example.